# Ajax listener of f:ajax not called on first execution only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, richfaces, composite-component

I've a strange problem on ajax listener execution of an jsf page using Mojarra 2.1.13 and Richfaces 4.2.3.Final on JBoss AS 6.1. I've tried to reproduce the problem within the following example, but the *problem doesn't occur within this example*.

**index.xhtml**

I've inserted the `rich:jQuery` element to force jQuery inclusion, becaue in my real application the command button of the form is hidden and executed per `jQuery('#one:form:submit').click();` method.

```
<h:body>
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="app.js"/>
    <rich:jQuery selector="document" query="ready(function(){app.init();})" timing="domready"/>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block">
        <c:forEach items="#{testBean.values}" var="value">  
            <c:if test="true">
                <test:component id="#{value}" value="#{value}">
                    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{testBean.submit}" render=":out" />
                </test:component>
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
        <h:outputText value="#{testBean.text}" id="out" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:body>
```

**resources/test/component.xhtml**

The composite component used within the content.

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="value" />
    <composite:clientBehavior name="click" event="click" targets="form:submit" default="true"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:form id="form" styleClass="objects">
        <h:inputText id="input" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"/>
        <h:commandButton id="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </h:form>
</composite:implementation>
```

**com.example.TestBean**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "testBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TestBean.class);
    private String text;
    private List<String> values;

    // Getters + Setter 

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        setText("instanziated");
        setValues(new ArrayList<String>());
        getValues().add("one");
        getValues().add("two");
        LOGGER.info("TestBean initialized");
    }

    public void submit(final AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        LOGGER.info("executed");
        setText("executed");
    }
}
```

In the real application the ajax event is fired when the submit button is clicked but the listener method isn't invoked, **but after** the first execution everything works like expected, ajax request is sent and listener method is invoked. This apperance happens until the whole page is reloaded.

---

UPDATE:

As requested within the comments, this is a part of the real application. The application has some draggable elements and the changes were submitted to the server to store the changes on server side. Therefore the `operation` is set to `drag` to a hidden input field. Furthermore the changes were converted to JSON which is set into a second hidden input `value`. When these values were set, the submit button is called to invoke the ajax request.

```
var app : {
    init : function() {
        jQuery(".objects").draggable({
            // event handling
            stop : function(event, ui) {
                // send changes to server
                app.submitDragOperation(this);
            }
        });
    },
    submitDragOperation : function(form) {
        app.setOperation(form,
            "drag",
            JSON.stringify({
                top: jQuery(form).css("top"),
                left: jQuery(form).css("left")
            })
        );
        app.submitOperation(form);
    },
    setOperation : function(form, operation, value) {

        var inputOpId = helper.fn.escapeColons("#" + jQuery(form).attr("id") + ":operation");
        var inputValId = helper.fn.escapeColons("#" + jQuery(form).attr("id") + ":value")
        jQuery(inputOpId).val(operation);
        jQuery(inputValId).val(value);
    },
    submitOperation : function(form) {
        // evaluate id of submit button
        var submitId = helper.fn.escapeColons("#" + jQuery(form).attr("id") + ":submit");
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(submitId).click();
        });
    },
    submitDragOperation : function(form) {
        app.setOperation(form,
            "drag",
            JSON.stringify({
                top: jQuery(form).css("top"),
                left: jQuery(form).css("left")
            })
        );
        app.submitOperation(form);
    }
};
```

Comment: what does output source script look like?

Comment: do you mean the js script which invokes the submit button click? or what output source script do you mean?

Comment: the js in browser source view.. live code, yes that contains submit handler, ajax etc

Comment: Without really looking at the code, the question title indicates a possible cause as described in point 6 of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183 Have you excluded this?